# how to test location services while google play services do not run on emulator?

Tags: android

I have a problem. I'm building a application which uses GPS locations.

The problem is, that I can not use it in the emulator because of "Note: Google Play services is not supported on the Android emulator — to develop using the APIs, you need to provide a development device such as an Android phone or tablet."

Is there a way to send fake locations to a real android device to test my application?

Usually I do it with the Window > Show View > Other > Emulator Control.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just login and install Google Play Services on the emulator

Comment: On the emulator, login to your gmail account, go to playstore and install Google Play Services

Comment: I dont have the play store on the emulator

Answer (score 3):

Yes actually, you must open the DDMS option. Inside you can go to the emulator controls and send it longitude and lattitude coordinates. Here is a link to explain it in detail http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#console

**Note** 
You also must have an `AVD` with the `Google API` in order to do this. So if you're testing this you might for instance need an `AVD` that has API 14. On creation of the `AVD` there will be two options. One says API 14, the other will say *API 14 Google*, which is the one you want so it can use the services you need.

**Edit**
Here is a link that may help you if you need to "see" the map http://code.google.com/p/android-gps-emulator/
 Using an `AVD` created with the Google API I never had a problem seeing my maps though. I must admit it has been a while since I used an `AVD`, using an actual Tablet or Phone with `Android` is much faster and more reliable.

Comment: The problem is I cant see the map because I'm using the google play services which are not supported on a AVD as posted in my question

Comment: oh, I wasn't aware you needed to "see" the map. I will edit the answer with a link that may help you

Comment: it was no problem, but the second time: now its not possible anymore with the google play services which now provides the goog maps api v2 for android

Comment: this would be much easier for you if you just tested this on an actual phone or tablet. Otherwise the resources I posted above are the only ones I know of